# Using callback function inside array.map javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to bcrypt password for every user in an array.

```
router.post("/insertuser", (req, res) => {

  var promises = users.map((item) => {

    bcrypt.genSalt(10)
      .then((salt) => {
        return item
      })    
  })

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      res.json({
        "data": results
      })
    })    
})//end route
```

But I am getting results = [undefined,undefined].

How can I return array element from **bcrypt.genSalt(10).then**

Please help as I am new to ES6

EDIT: My user users array is like this:

[{ "username": "admin", "admin": true}
    ]

Comment: your map callback doesn't return anything, therefore, promises will be an array of `undefined` - you need to return something in `(item) => { /* here */}`

Comment: How can I correct that. I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: ... perhaps `return bcrypt.genSalt(10)` - that way you're **return**ing something

Comment: But i want to update user.password field inside the .map

Comment: Or just don’t use a block. Just use …`.map(item => bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => item))`.

Comment: `But i want to update user.password field inside the .map` which part of your code does that? I don't even know what that means in context of your code - do you understand that `.then((salt) => {
        return item
      })` is still executed if you `return bcrypt.genSalt(10).then......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return the promise from `bcrypt.genSalt`.

```
router.post("/insertuser", (req, res) => {

  var promises = users.map((item) => {

    return bcrypt.genSalt(10)
      .then((salt) => {
        return item
      })    
  })

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      res.json({
        "data": results
      })
    })    
})//end route
```

Comment: `Simply return the bcrypt.genSalt's result.` - it's actually going to return the Promise, not the result, and the resolved value will be `item`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `.then()` after any promise it will directly get resolved. In your code `users.map()` will run synchronously and the promises will have undefined.
Here is the code you can use :

```
router.post("/insertuser", (req, res) => {
    var promises = users.map((item) => {
      return bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    })

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => {
        console.log(results)
    });  
})//
```

Also notice that salt is used to generate hash. You are only generating salt. To generate hash of password also add `bcrypt.hash(password,salt)`. Here is the code :

```
var promises = users.map((item) => {
  return bcrypt.genSalt(10);
})

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    promises = results.map((item, index) => {
      return bcrypt.hash(users[index], item);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```